# Basic JQuery Slideshow add pagination limit

Tags: jquery, pagination, slideshow

I've recently installed to my PHP website a simple and Basic JQuery Slideshow and everything is going fine until now.
The point is that when there is a lot of pictures on database, the image numeration fills the page and get a new line.

Here is my jQuery Slideshow: ([myjqueryslideshow](https://github.com/jcobb/basic-jquery-slider))

I've been looking for something to limit the numeration to show just 5 numbers and I found this jQuery pagination script: ([myjquerypagination](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2009/11/17/jpaginate-a-fancy-jquery-pagination-plugin/))

Any idea about how to limit my images numeration or implement part of the pagination codes to my slideshow script?

Here's the lines from my jQuery Slideshow script where I believe that is the numeration:

```
T=function(){
    l=e('<ol class="bjqs-markers"></ol>');
    e.each(o,function(t,n){
        var i=t+1,
        s=t+1;
        r.animtype==="slide"&&(s=t+2);
        var o=e('<li><a title="Image '+i+'" href="#">'+i+"</a></li>"); //numeration button
        i===v.currentslide&&o.addClass("active-marker");
        o.on("click","a",function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        !v.animating&&v.currentslide!==s&&O(!1,s)
        });
    o.appendTo(l)
    });
    l.appendTo(i);
    c=l.find("li");
    if(r.centermarkers){
        l.addClass("h-centered");
        var t=(r.width-l.width())/2;
        l.css("left",t)
    }
},
```

[image]